# How much aging do people suffer while in stasis?

Tags: alien-covenant

In *Alien: Covenant*, it is estimated that it would take them another 7 years plus to arrive at their original destination. It is obvious that everyone onboard the *Covenant* is frozen.

Does sleeping in stasis slow down the aging process at all? Or is it just a way to conserve food, water, and oxygen, and keep people sane?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, it helps a little in aging factor, slowing down aging somehow. other facts are obvious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia page for Amanda Ripley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanda_Ripley_(character)):

> A deleted scene from the 1986 theatrical version of ***Aliens***, reinserted into the Special Edition first released in 1992, reveals that Ellen Ripley (played by Sigourney Weaver) has a daughter, Amanda. **Amanda was ten years old when Ellen travels into space** before the events of ***Alien***. Amanda became an adult, married (taking on the surname McClaren), and **died during her mother's 57-year stasis between the events of the first two films**. A picture of Amanda as an elderly adult is shown to Ripley. The picture is one of Weaver's real-life mother, Elizabeth Inglis.

So based on that, stasis seems to virtually halt the aging process.

Comment: I think this is a detail that Alien movie creator overlooked / unable to produce in the movies. As in covenant, each stasis pod has a heart beat monitor on it, and its reading is not zero. I think in order to halt aging process, we need to stop the heart beat to virtually zero.

Comment: @YuZhang .... stasis pods are future magic, I don't think you can place rules on it like that.  Who knows how they cease the aging process.